# how encode a php code in three ways Like -> base64 & str_rot13 & gzinflate

Tags: php, encoding, base64

i am a little bit cofused about three ways encoding of php codes (`base64 & str_rot13 & gzinflate!`)specially for `str_rot13 and gzinflate` ways.
the latest php file after encoding should be like this :

```
<?php
eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('Your Encoded string'))));
?>
```

for example this is my php codes:

```
<?php
echo('This Is A PHP Code');
?>
```

learn me step by step how to encode these php codes?
i could n't find any online encoders about this, just many decoders!
i am looking for the fastest ways, because i want to use these encoding method always.
i think the step 1 and 2 are like below :
1- convert that php codes to this :

```
?><?php
echo('This Is A PHP Code');
?><?php
```

2-encode codes in step 1 form here :
[base_64 encoder](http://www.webutils.pl/Base64)
3-?????? help me

really appreciate for attention

Comment: I really don't get the question ? Because i have the feeling that the question is already answered ?_? Otherwise have you tried to read the PHP.Manual, you should get more detailed info about those functions ...

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? The techniques you're describing are typically used by injected malware.

Comment: hi, i think learning purpose is a good idea. on earth many people using this method and i want to learn how(just this... and this example is enough for me) i am asp.net web developer and that is why i asked such this Q in stack from php developers. i have some problems about str_rot13 and specially gzinflate. how do these functions work? i couldn't find an example for both of them two ways encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample PHP code which works with eval().

```
<?php // sample answer by chathurya
/*
$string  = '<?php echo \'<p>Hello World</p>\'; ?> ';
*/

$string  = ' echo \'<p>Hello World</p>\'; ?> ';
$encoded = base64_encode(str_rot13(gzdeflate($string)));
$uncompressed = gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode($encoded)));

eval($uncompressed);
?>
```

Note : The string you need to encode must not contain

Answer (score 0):

```
#Something like this 
<?php
$a='<?php echo "hallo";'; // php script
$a=urlencode(gzdeflate($a)); // encode 
$b=gzinflate(urldecode($a)); // decode
eval('?>'.$b); // exec encoded php script
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$code='<?php echo "hallo world";';
$encode=rawurlencode(gzdeflate($code));

echo gzinflate(rawurldecode($encode));

eval('?>'.gzinflate(rawurldecode($encode)));
```

another example https://github.com/Cvar1984/ecode